# comparing event listener with variable integer

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, event-listener, keydown

I'm actually practicing with event listener. I'm trying to do a very simple game where an arrow shows up and the user matches it on the keyboard . If it's correct score increases and if it's not score is reset.

It's working ok but when the arrow is not matched the if statement who resets the score is not triggered and the score is increased instead.

Here is my code (i apologize it's not clean)

```
const fleche = document.querySelector('.fas');
const showScore = document.querySelector('#score');
window.addEventListener('keydown',compare);
let score = 0;
let jet = 0;

showScore.innerHTML=`Score : ${score}`;
function jetdes(){
     jet = Math.floor(Math.random()*4+1);
     randomArrow();
}
function randomArrow(){
switch (jet) {
    
    case 1:
        fleche.classList.remove('fa-arrow-up','fa-arrow-down','fa-arrow-left','fa-arrow-right');
        fleche.classList.add('fa-arrow-up');
        
    break;
    case 2:
        fleche.classList.remove('fa-arrow-up','fa-arrow-down','fa-arrow-left','fa-arrow-right');
        fleche.classList.add('fa-arrow-down');
        
    break;
    case 3:
        fleche.classList.remove('fa-arrow-up','fa-arrow-down','fa-arrow-left','fa-arrow-right');
        fleche.classList.add('fa-arrow-left');
        
    break;
    case 4:
        fleche.classList.remove('fa-arrow-up','fa-arrow-down','fa-arrow-left','fa-arrow-right');
        fleche.classList.add('fa-arrow-right');
        
    break;
}}

function compare(e){
if(e.code='ArrowUp' && jet === 1){
    score++;
    showScore.innerHTML=`Score : ${score}`;
    console.log(1);
    jetdes();
    
}
else if(e.code='ArrowDown' && jet === 2){
    score++;
    showScore.innerHTML=`Score : ${score}`;
    console.log(2);
    jetdes();
    
}
else if(e.code='ArrowLeft' && jet === 3){
    score++;
    showScore.innerHTML=`Score : ${score}`;
    console.log(3);
    jetdes();
    
}
else if(e.code='ArrowRight' && jet === 4){
    score++;
    showScore.innerHTML=`Score : ${score}`;
    console.log(4);
    jetdes();
    
}
else {
    score = 0;
    showScore.innerHTML=`Score : ${score}`;
    console.log(5);
    jetdes();
    
}
}

jetdes();
```

I know it's probably an obvious mistake but i've been scratching my head over that for a while.

Thanks !

Comment: inside your if statements it should be `e.code == 'Arrow...'` instead of `e.code='Arrow...'`

Comment: Classic. Thank you so much.